# Encryption type

Tags: encryption, passwords

Who can tell me what type of encryption this is?: 
ntmQADJg9WWFHqQU/Bcef0YRnM0xB1

Comment: And the follow up question will be what key was used to encrypt it? You'll need another approach to decipher that...

Comment: That's the combination on my luggage!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_64) encoded string. However decoding that results in a binary, so beyond that can't say.